# got undefined to passing data react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i always got *undefined* when i click the submit button on modalAction
if I do console.log (projectData) in my action modal to see all the data, how do I pass project data from  in modalAction to projectAction?

*/src/view/projectList.js*

```
const ProjectList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const project = useSelector(state => state.project)
    const modal = useSelector(state => state.modal)
    const category = useSelector(state => state.category)

    // Open New Project Modal
    const handleOpenProjectModal = () => {
        dispatch(openModal(category.categories, project.data))
    }

    return (
        <Button 
            label="Add Project" 
            onClick={()=> handleOpenProjectModal()}
            primary={true}
        />  
    )
```

*/src/store/action/modalAction.js*

```
export const openModal = (categoryList, projectData) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        <Button 
            label='Submit'
            onClick={() => dispatch(createProject(projectData))}
            primary={true}
        />
    })
```

*/src/store/action/projectAction.js*

```
export const createProject = (data) => dispatch => {

try {
    instance.post('/project', data)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_PROJECT,
            message: res.data.message
        })
        instance.get('/project')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PROJECTS,
                payload: res.data.data
            })
        })
        dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    })
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: PROJECTS_ERROR,
        payload: error,
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Didn't catch what you mean but why would you ever need to dispatch a Button? in modalAction.js. You should be return a React component that contains the Button, in this React component, you have natural access to project like project list. Do not need to pass this around components.

Comment: I want to make my <modal /> more dynamic with one modal but its contents always change according to the <button /> that is clicked, maybe this can make the application lighter.

the only problem is passing data to the <button /> in the modalAction.js which is sent from productList.js to projectAction.js.

Comment: data in modalAction.js contains data{title : 'string', body: 'string'}, 
and when I click the data returns to the initialState > data{title: null, body: null}

Comment: With limited information, I can't really tell why it's not working. You mean data in redux? Or upon dispatching the button, projectData contains up to date info, then onClick, becomes init object in projectAction.js?

Comment: https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state

Comment: I have done several ways but maybe I know why the data is not entered, maybe it is wrong when the onChange value of the input. because when I change the data from the input value the data has not been entered. and I re-opened the modal and the data was sent.

Comment: it's a crazy way to make things difficult for myself lol.